# Adding Mouseover Effect to Submit Button (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

Quick question, I'm trying to add a rollover effect to a submit button, but it doesn't seem to be working. i originally used CSS to create the effect but CSS creates a bit of a flicker when the the image is rolled over (my guess is from loading the rollover image).

Heres the code for the button:

```
<%= image_submit_tag ("sharebutton_up.jpg"), :mouseover => ("sharebutton_down.jpg")%>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this code, or a different way to create the rollover effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an image sprite and alter it using the background position.

```
<%= image_submit_tag ("sharebutton.jpg"), :class => "submit_button" %>
```

Then in your CSS

```
.submit_button {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background-image: url("sharebutton.jpg");
}

.submit_button:hover {
   background-position: 0 -100%;
 }
```

This assumes a 100x100 image, with the top half being the off state and the bottom half being the on stat.  See [this link](http://www.elated.com/articles/css-rollover-buttons/) for more information.

Comment: @BTHarris Looks like accepting an answer gave you the required reputaiton.  :)  http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up

Comment: Hi ! I'm wondering how to do the same thing properly when the image is in a table ? Because if I do exactly what you say, the image is not cropped at all, and I can see all states of the sprite. The only way I found to do this was to link a transparent image `image_submit_tag ("empty_image.png")` with the exact same dimension as one of the sprite state.